# IndentationError: unexpected indent

Tags: python

Este programa en Python para encontrar la solución de una ecuación de segundo grado y discernir si esta es un número complejo, me resulta en el siguiente error:

```
"message": "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level",
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Es un error de indentación pero por mucho que vuelva a indentar todo sigue dando el mismo error.

El programa es el siguiente:

```
from math import sqrt
class Ecuaciones2Grado():
    def __init__(self):
        self.interfaz()
    def calcular(self, A, B, C):
        if ((B**2)-4*A*C) < 0:
            print("La solución de la ecuación es con números complejos")
        else:
            int x1, x2
            x1 = (-B+sqrt(B**2-(4*A*C)))/(2*A)
            x2 = (-B-sqrt(B**2-(4*A*C)))/(2*A)
            print("Las soluciones de la ecuación son:", x1, x2)

    def interfaz(self):
        A = int(input("Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable cuadrática\n"))
        B = int(input("Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable lineal\n"))
        C = int(input("Ingrese el término independiente\n"))
        
        self.calcular(A, B, C)
```

Comment: En qué línea te indica el error?

Comment: No me marca ningún error. ¿Qué significa `int x1, x2`?

Comment: En la 8, 9 y 11 @jachguate

Comment: Intento declarar las variables @CandidMoe

Comment: Eso es código C; en Python no se declaran las variables.

Comment: Quizás tu código usa tabuladores en algunas líneas y espacios en otras. Asegúrate de que tu editor te permite convertir todo en espacios y úsalo siempre así

Comment: He intentado quitar la declaración de variables y convertirlo todo a espacios y sigue dando el mismo error. También he probado a cambiar de editor.

Comment: El código que has publicado aquí no provoca el error que mencionas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Código**:

```
from math import sqrt
class Ecuaciones2Grado():
    def __init__(self):
        self.interfaz()
    def calcular(self, A, B, C):
        if ((B**2)-4*A*C) < 0:
            print("La solución de la ecuación es con números complejos")
        else:
            x1 = (-B+sqrt(B**2-(4*A*C)))/(2*A)
            x2 = (-B-sqrt(B**2-(4*A*C)))/(2*A)
            print("Las soluciones de la ecuación son:", x1, x2)

    def interfaz(self):
        A = int(input("Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable cuadrática\n"))
        B = int(input("Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable lineal\n"))
        C = int(input("Ingrese el término independiente\n"))
        
        return [None, A, B, C]

Ecuacion = Ecuaciones2Grado
valores = Ecuacion.interfaz(None)
Ecuacion.calcular(valores[0], valores[1], valores[2], valores[3])
```

**Explicación**:

`interfaz()` devuelve una lista según los valores introducidos por el usuario. La lista se guarda en la variable `valores`. Se llama a `calcular()` con los elementos de la lista.

He cambiado toda la indentación a espacios, y ahora funciona correctamente. Es posible que el error `IndentationError: unexpected indent` fuera debido a usar en unos casos espacios y en otros tabulación.

**Resultado**:

Ejemplo 1, con A = 1, B = 10 y C = 1, solución con números reales:

```
Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable cuadrática
1
Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable lineal
10
Ingrese el término independiente
1
Las soluciones de la ecuación son: -0.10102051443364424 -9.898979485566356
```

Ejemplo 2, con A = 10, B = 5 y C = 10, solución con números complejos:

```
Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable cuadrática
10
Ingrese el coeficiente de la variable lineal
5
Ingrese el término independiente
10
La solución de la ecuación es con números complejos
```

Comment: Pero ¿cómo responde esto a la pregunta del usuario? ¿Dónde estaba su error de indentación?

Comment: Gracias, lo he añadido en la explicación